# Vimeo froogaloop conflict with plugin

Tags: jquery, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player, froogaloop

I am using the plugin [Vimeowrap Playlist](http://luwes.co/labs/vimeo-playlist/) to make a playlist of videos from a certain channel. That is working just fine, but now I need to track the events of the videos: play, pause etc. When I use froogaloop to do that, I get the error `Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined`. Somehow froogaloop is conflicting with Vimeowrap script. Can anyone help me with this problem?

This is the plugin code:

```
vimeowrap('player').setup({
    urls: [
        'https://vimeo.com/channels/trocadero'
    ],
    height:363,
    item: 5,
    plugins: {
        'playlist':{
            position:'right',
            size:340
        }
    },



});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nepgs0k4/) of my whole problem.

Comment: See the API example here:
http://labs.funkhausdesign.com/examples/vimeo/froogaloop2-api-basics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve my problem...here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7b4ot2s/) solution.

```
var vimeoPlayers = [];

function VimeoPlayer (playerId) {
var iframe = $('#' + playerId),
  contentWindow = iframe[0].contentWindow,
  targetOriginUrl = iframe.attr('src').split('?')[0];
console.log(iframe);
console.log(contentWindow);
console.log(targetOriginUrl);

contentWindow.postMessage({ 'method': 'addEventListener', 'value': 'pause' }, "http:"+targetOriginUrl);
contentWindow.postMessage({ 'method': 'addEventListener', 'value': 'play' }, "http:"+targetOriginUrl);

return {
play: function () {
    contentWindow.postMessage({ 'method': 'play' }, "http:"+targetOriginUrl);

},

pause: function() {
  contentWindow.postMessage({ 'method': 'pause' }, "http:"+targetOriginUrl);

},

unload: function() {
  contentWindow.postMessage({ 'method': 'unload' }, "http:"+targetOriginUrl);
}
}
}

// Listen for postMessage events
$(window).on('message', function(e) {
var data = $.parseJSON(e.originalEvent.data);

if (data.event === 'ready') {
var vimeoPlayer = new VimeoPlayer(data.player_id);

vimeoPlayers.push(vimeoPlayer);
}
if(data.event==='play'){
   console.log('play');
 }
 if(data.event==='pause'){
   console.log('pause');
 }

 console.log(data);
});



$('.vimeo-controls .pause-all').on('click', function () {
for (var i = 0; i < vimeoPlayers.length; i++) {
vimeoPlayers[i].pause();
}
 });

$('.vimeo-controls .play-all').on('click', function () {
for (var i = 0; i < vimeoPlayers.length; i++) {
vimeoPlayers[i].play();
}
 });

$('.vimeo-controls .unload-all').on('click', function () {
for (var i = 0; i < vimeoPlayers.length; i++) {
 vimeoPlayers[i].unload();
 }
   });
```

Comment: Can you please provide a summary of what your solution is? Doing a manual diff to your question is not very helpful.